# Wordpress localhost not working

Tags: php, wordpress, web, localhost, wamp

I am new to wordpress so please assist.

I know there have been some questions regarding this already there but it did not work hence asking for assistance

I have cloned a live repo and saved it in my WAMP www folder which I normally use for other php sites and refer it using localhost/project/ but now when I am trying this it is redirecting to https://localhost/project/

I performed following steps

1) Set up my db connection in wp-config.php

2) added these 2 lines in wp-config

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost/project');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/project');
```

3) turned WP_CACHE to false in wp-config.php

I don't know what else to do so please assist.

Comment: Try add prefix `http://` before localhost/project on 2 line you provide.

Comment: did not work.. same issue

Comment: The issue is the website keep redirect to https://localhost/project? Take a look at your plugins directory if any https or SSL in plugin folder name.

Comment: So what is the error, is anything coming on any fatal error coming, change wp_debug to true on wp-config.php and let me know

Comment: If i deactivate plugins then it shows error for divis theme functions.php

Comment: Do you have a Virtual Host defines for this project? If not you really should, specially for WP sites

Comment: I do not server access to this code .. I am only given a bitbucket repo access and I need to get this to work on my local so that I can add code and test before creating PR.

Comment: Do you have a HTTP to HTTPS redirect in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

If it does not work, you can try using php built-in server.
Go to your project root directory and execute the below command in console.

php -S localhost:8000

Comment: it is faling and adding https://localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

I can mention some basic steps without having much knowledge about your installation,

1. Go to phpmyadmin, option wp_options, change `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` values, no need to define on wp-config.php
2. Rename your plugins folder to something like "plugins1" and access admin, if you can access then go straight to update your Permalink.
3. After updating permalinks rename plugins folder back to `plugins` then access plugin section on wp-admin.

**UPDATE**

After migration you are advised to replace all urls through out data base with old url. Please checkout the following plugin, it will surely help you out.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Let me know if still finding issue.

Comment: sorry it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Its because of plugins that redirect like you may use some security plugin, Please deactivate all plugins ( to deactivate all plugins from database please check this link https://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-disable-plugins-via-database-manual-removal.html  )and delete cache folder and change base url from database no need to change config file

You can check base url for database here . url (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings)
Let me know if it helps

Last this you can try edit config file to show error reporting so that if any error related to custom it will display(Wp-config.php file change this define('WP_DEBUG', true); true to show errors). Thanks

Comment: Theme file is giving an error if I deactivate plugins

Comment: Send me error what divi file gives

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bp_is_active() in C:\wamp64\www\adsmoi\wp-content\themes\project-divi\functions.php on line 1165

Comment: Activate only single plugin that is related to bp_is_active seems its buddypress please activate that plugin only

Comment: how to activate this as I am not able to open the wordpress dashboard on my localhost?

Comment: You can follow here 
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199798/activate-a-plugin-through-phpmyadmin-or-ftp

here change a and like they did, let me know if any doubt

Comment: In wp_options table try to search active_plugins then one row will be shown , Then please edit it for example
a:10:{
    i:0;s:49:"1and1-wordpress-wizard/1and1-wordpress-wizard.php";
}
a:10 -- count of activate plugin in our case it should be 1
i:0 ---- 0 for deactivate and 1 for actiavte viceversa you may check this ..
Please update this and let me know if it works

Comment: did not follow the last part of how to deactivate the plugin

Comment: goto databse and wp_options table may be you have different prefix , so goto _options table first and let me know

Comment: a:27:{i:0;s:65:"BuddyPress-User-Account-Type/buddypress-user-account-type-pro.php";i:1;s:36:"acf-field-video-master/acf-video.php";i:2;s:33:"adsmoi-manager/adsmoi-manager.php";i:3;s:17:"adsmoi/adsmoi.php";

Comment: here like 
i have omnly one plugin activate 
a:1:{i:0;s:9:"hello.php";}

Comment: a total and rest take onyl list of activate plugin remove rest

Comment: so like this a:1:{i:0;s:65:"BuddyPress-User-Account-Type/buddypress-user‌​-account-type-pro.ph‌​p";}   ?

Comment: yes right please do this, enable all plugins related to buddy press, Create list with all buddypress plugin with count a